# In Java, can I somehow move field to superclass if subclasses have different types for them?

Tags: java, field, subclass, superclass

In my Java program, I have two classes that are really similar, and it would make a lot of sense to create a superclass for them to subclass and generalize a bunch of their methods.

The only problem is that one of their key fields is implemented in one as a `Queue` and in one as a `PriorityQueue`.

Is there any way to superclass these and somehow generalize the field type and let the subclasses pick what it will perhaps on instantiation?

```
public Base{

}

public Sub1{
     Queue<Customer> customers;
}

public Sub2{
     PriorityQueue<Customer> customers;
}
```

Comment: `Queue<T>` is a supertype of `PriorityQueue<T>` , so why not declare `customers` as a `Queue<T>` in `Base` and choose the implementation in the subclasses as you suggested?

Comment: `Queue` is just an interface. Shouldn't be too difficult to implement this in a generic queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) implements [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#method.summary). If you want to delegate creation to subclasses, have them pass the appropriate `Queue` to use to the base constructor:

```
public class Base {
    protected final Queue<Customer> customers;

    protected Base(Queue<Customer> c) {
        this.customers = c;
    }
}

public class Sub1 extends Base {
     Sub1() {
        super(new WhateverQueue<Customer>());
     }
}

public class Sub2 extends Base {
     Sub2() {
         super(new PriorityQueue<Customer>());
     }
}
```

I should mention that if `Sub2` needs to use methods that are specific to `PriorityQueue` (such as [`comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#comparator--)) in some `Sub2`-specific method, it can either:

1. Cast `customers` (since it knows that `customers` is actually a `PriorityQueue<Customer>`, not just a `Queue<Customer>`), or
2. Declare its own instance field which will keep the typed reference:

   ```
   private PriorityQueue<Customer> priorityCustomers;

   Sub2() {
       super(new PriorityQueue<Customer>());
       this.priorityCustomers = (PriorityQueue<Customer>)(this.customers);
   }
   ```

#2 keeps the casting required to a minimum and nicely contained to just the constructor, making it easier to change `PriorityQueue<Customer>` to something else later.

Comment: Shouldn't the field be non-final?

Comment: @SamTebbs33: Probably not, in general with this pattern it's better to only allow the field to be assigned once, in `Base`. But you can leave off `final` if you want to open it up to subclasses replacing it ad hoc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If the two subclasses only differ in terms of one field which is the queue, I don't see much value in creating two subclasses. One class with queue implementations that can be swapped should do.

Comment: Oh, I  didn't realise that final fields can be assigned in constructors. I thought they had to be assigned at the point of declaration. But since all non-static fields are assigned in a constructor (in the bytecode), I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @CKing: It's clear from the question that there's a lot that can be moved to `Base`, but that there's still a need for the subclasses. The parts that can't be moved have just been (appropriately) left out the question, as they're not relevant.

Comment: @SamTebbs33: From [JLS§8.3.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2): *"A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned at the end of every constructor of the class in which it is declared"* So not just a bytecode thing, a language specification thing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

priorityqueue is a subclass of abstract queue which implements queue, so basically base could have a queue of customers.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have the queue of `customers` as a dependency in `Base` and let the client code decide what queue to instantiate.

```
public Base{
  private Queue<Customer> customers;

  protected Base(Queue<Customer> customers) {
     this.queue = queue;
  }

}
```

You don't need the `Sub1` and `Sub2` classes since they only differ from `Base` in terms of the queue used. Client code can simply decide what queue to use :

```
Base baseWithQueue = new Base(new ArrayBlockingQueue<Customer>());
Base baseWithPriorityQueue = new Base(new PriorirityQueue<Customer>());
```

Comment: `Queue` is an interface, you can't write `new Queue<Customer>()`. Unless you follow that with a lengthy anonymous class declaration :P

Comment: @Amine My bad. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The `PriorityQueue` class implements the `Queue` interface, so I'd recommend making `Base` an abstract class and keep the `customers` collection (of type `Queue`) in there. Then instantiate `customers` from `Sub1` or `Sub2`'s constructor as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you implement the field as  `Queue`, you can instantiate the field as a `PriorityQueue` in `Sub2`, because `PriorityQueue` implements `Queue` (source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

```
public Base{
     Queue<Customer> customers;
     public Base(Queue<Customers> queue){
         this.customers = queue;
     }
}

public Sub1{
    public Sub1(){
        super(new Queue<Customer>());
    }
}

public Sub2{
     public Sub2(){
        super(new PriorityQueue<Customer>());
    }
}
```

However, when you need to use the `customers` field as a `PriorityQueue` (rather than a `Queue`) inside `Sub2`, you will need to cast it to a `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to give your `customers` attribute the general `Queue` type, which will give you flexibility. But if you want to enforce specific implementations in a given subclass, and carry that information in the rest of your program, you can use generic constraints :

```
public class Base<Q extends Queue<Customers>> {
    protected Q customers;

    public Base(Q customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
}

public Sub1 extends Base<Queue<Customers>> {
   public Sub1(Queue<String> customers) {
      super(customers);
   }
}

public Sub2 extends Base<PriorityQueue<Customers>>{
   public Sub2() {
       // Sub2 only supports PriorityQueues
      super(new PriorityQueue<String>());
   }
}
```

This can be useful, as it allows you to call, say, `customers.comparator()` inside `Sub2` without having to cast `customers` into a `PriorityQueue`.